# How to check if bytes variable is empty?

Tags: solidity, bytes

I have a mapping in my smart contract with `bytes32` keys and `bytes` values. How can I check if `bytes` value exists for specific key?
Mapping is something like this:

```
mapping(bytes32 => bytes) public Countries;
```

Comment: ## This solution stands for `bytes32`: ```
Countries[_user] == "" // Returns true if `Countries[_user]` is not initialized
``` --- pragma solidity ^0.6.0; mapping(address => bytes32) public Countries; function isCountriesInitialized(address _user) external view returns (bool) { if (Countries[_user] == "") return false; return true; } --- I observe that on `solidity v0.6.0` it may return 32 for length even though it is not mapped. Example of its returned value: `b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check it via `.length`. It will be 0 if it is empty/uninitialised.

```
Countries[key].length
```

Comment: On solc v.0.6.0 this actually returns True, It sees `b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'` as length 32 @ivicaa